# Inherit from abstract class Django

Tags: django

I am building a platform with 3 users roles: Admin, Creator and Brand. I redefined a default django User to be able to login by email.

```
class AbstractUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=32, unique=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=32, blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=64, blank=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=120, blank=True)
    bio = models.TextField(blank=True)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    EMAIL_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

    objects = CustomUserManager()

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email
```

I made this class an abstract one to be able to add new classes, inherit from the Abstract class and redefine their attributes.

```
class PlatformAdmin(AbstractUser):
    pass


class Creator(AbstractUser):
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=32, unique=True, error_messages={
        'unique': "A customer with that email already exists.",
    })

class Brand(AbstractUser):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
```

I also add in settings.py following:

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'users.PlatformAdmin'
```

Now when I run makemigrations it will give the following output:

```
users.Brand.groups: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'Brand.groups' clashes with reverse accessor for 'Creator.groups'.
        HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'Brand.groups' or 'Creator.groups'.
users.Brand.groups: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'Brand.groups' clashes with reverse accessor for 'PlatformAdmin.groups'.
        HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'Brand.groups' or 'PlatformAdmin.groups'.
users.Brand.user_permissions: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'Brand.user_permissions' clashes with reverse accessor for 'Creator.user_permissions'.
        HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'Brand.user_permissions' or 'Creator.user_permissions'.
users.Brand.user_permissions: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'Brand.user_permissions' clashes with reverse accessor for 'PlatformAdmin.user_permissions'.
        HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'Brand.user_permissions' or 'PlatformAdmin.user_permissions'.
users.Creator.groups: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'Creator.groups' clashes with reverse accessor for 'Brand.groups'.
        HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'Creator.groups' or 'Brand.groups'.
users.Creator.groups: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'Creator.groups' clashes with reverse accessor for 'PlatformAdmin.groups'.
        HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'Creator.groups' or 'PlatformAdmin.groups'.
users.Creator.user_permissions: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'Creator.user_permissions' clashes with reverse accessor for 'Brand.user_permissions'.
        HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'Creator.user_permissions' or 'Brand.user_permissions'.
users.Creator.user_permissions: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'Creator.user_permissions' clashes with reverse accessor for 'PlatformAdmin.user_permissions'.
        HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'Creator.user_permissions' or 'PlatformAdmin.user_permissions'.
users.PlatformAdmin.groups: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'PlatformAdmin.groups' clashes with reverse accessor for 'Brand.groups'.
        HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'PlatformAdmin.groups' or 'Brand.groups'.
users.PlatformAdmin.groups: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'PlatformAdmin.groups' clashes with reverse accessor for 'Creator.groups'.
        HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'PlatformAdmin.groups' or 'Creator.groups'.
users.PlatformAdmin.user_permissions: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'PlatformAdmin.user_permissions' clashes with reverse accessor for 'Brand.user_permissions'.
        HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'PlatformAdmin.user_permissions' or 'Brand.user_permissions'.
users.PlatformAdmin.user_permissions: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'PlatformAdmin.user_permissions' clashes with reverse accessor for 'Creator.user_permissions'.
        HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'PlatformAdmin.user_permissions' or 'Creator.user_permissions'.
```

I can't figure out what I am doing wrong and how to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to add 3 fields like this:

```
class AbstractUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=32, unique=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=32, blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=64, blank=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=120, blank=True)
    bio = models.TextField(blank=True)

    # add this 3 fields
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_creater = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_brand = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    EMAIL_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

    objects = CustomUserManager()

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email

AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'users.CustomUserModel'
```

I think you have to follow this method.

Comment: It won't allow me redefine attributes

Answer (score 0):

inside AbstractUser in class Meta, abstract=True is creating the problem. also you are repeating the email field in 2 places (AbstractUser and Creator).
OR 
keep only one user model(PlatformAdmin). convert Creator and Brand as normal model. otherwise fields from PermissionsMixin class are clashing(same fields are repeating in multiple places).